# Formatting Jquery Script the correct way

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a better way of formatting the below script? It does the job, but I wanted to see if there was a way to compile it into an if statement

This is an 'is this page helpful' module I'm plugging in to my site using google tag manager to track clicks.

```
<div class="feedback-headline">
    <p class="feedback-heading">Was this page helpful?</p>
    <button class="feedback-button" id="feedback-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
    <button class="feedback-button" id="feedback-no" type="button">No</button>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#feedback-yes").click(function(){
        $(".feedback-button").hide();
        $(".feedback-headline").append("<p style='display:inline- 
        block;'>Thanks for your feedback!</p>");
    });
    $("#feedback-no").click(function(){
        $(".feedback-button").hide();
        $(".feedback-headline").append("<p style='display:inline-block;'>We're 
        sorry to hear that! We'll try to improve on it.</p>");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use event delegation on the container, and if the target is the `feedback-yes`, append with the yes-string, else append with the no-string:

```js
$('.feedback-headline').on('click', '.feedback-button', function(event) {
  $(".feedback-button").hide();
  $(".feedback-headline").append(`<p style='display:inline-block;'>${
    event.target.id === 'feedback-yes'
    ? 'Thanks for your feedback!'
    : "We're sorry to hear that! We'll try to improve on it."
  }</p>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feedback-headline">
  <p class="feedback-heading">Was this page helpful?</p>
  <button class="feedback-button" id="feedback-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
  <button class="feedback-button" id="feedback-no" type="button">No</button>
</div>
```